# jquery mobile guardar variáveis na aplicação

Tags: jquery, mobile

Olá

Estou a criar uma pequena app não e consigo fazer chamadas para números de telefone inseridos através de formulários.
Os dados são inseridos numa página de configurações:

`<div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <form action="" method="post" name="config"><label for="bombeiros">Bombeiros</label>
        <input name="bombeiros" type="text" id="bombeiros" value="" size="9" maxlength="9"  />
      </div>`

E as chamadas são feitas noutras páginas:

```
<td width="20%" height="45" align="center"><a rel="external" href="tel:+351333666999" ><img src="jquery-mobile/images/bombeiros.png" width="70" height="70"></td>
```

Assim faz chamadas para o nº 333666999, o que eu queria é que guardasse o número inserido no form das configurações e fizesse chamadas para esse nº. que apenas se perderia quando fosse substituído por outro no form.

Está tudo num index.html

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Você poderia colocar o html completo no codepen ou jsbin? Pelo que você explicou, acredito que é possível resolver só com javascript.

Comment: Olá, aqui está o código completo, sem imagens e css. https://codepen.io/zepadilha/pen/zBYNBO Obrigado